# Api for historical USD rates?

Tags: cardano-node, api, javascript, ethereum, solidity

I want to fetch the historical USD rates from a timestamp, is there any api available for that could be used in javascript?

Answer (score 2):

Coingecko is what comes to my mind. Checkout https://www.coingecko.com/en/api/documentation -> `/coins/{id}/history`